# Problems setting up product with plugins using AspectJ on Eclipse version 2024-03

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, aspectj

I have a set of Eclipse plugins, one of which uses aspects to modify the Eclipse compiler's behavior. Then, the product consisting of the aforementioned plugins plus some other official Eclipse plugins is built using Maven and Tycho. Everything was working perfectly fine on Eclipse version 2023-06 (and older versions) for a few years now. I tried to update my product to version 2024-03, and this is when the problem occurred.

When my product is started, the following exception is visible in the Error Log (FrameworkEvent ERROR thrown by org.eclipse.osgi plugin):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/TypeBinding$AjcClosure1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.CompletionEngine.<clinit>(CompletionEngine.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$8.optionsChanged(JavaModelManager.java:1989)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.addingService(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.addingService(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:947)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:257)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:230)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:907)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:956)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.registerDebugOptionsListener(JavaModelManager.java:1978)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.start(JavaCore.java:6652)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:775)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:987)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.ViewDescriptor.createView(ViewDescriptor.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:342)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:976)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:991)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:991)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.lambda$0(PartServiceImpl.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4803)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.DisplayUISynchronize.syncExec(DisplayUISynchronize.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.lambda$0(LazyStackRenderer.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4803)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.DisplayUISynchronize.syncExec(DisplayUISynchronize.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busySetPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:4032)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$12(WorkbenchPage.java:3969)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3969)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setup(WorkbenchWindow.java:896)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:976)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.inject(ContextInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StandardTrim.createStatusLine(StandardTrim.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StandardTrim.createWidget(StandardTrim.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:976)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolControlRenderer.createWidget(ToolControlRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:991)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarRenderer.processContents(TrimBarRenderer.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:271)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.TypeBinding$AjcClosure1 cannot be found by org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch_3.37.0.v20240215-1558
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 234 more
```

And this is only the beginning, because after importing some Maven projects, random errors with similar stack traces keep popping up.

Similar issues occurred in both Linux and Windows builds. I managed to resolve those issues on Linux by adding the following configuration to the product:

```
<plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
```

However, this solution did not resolve the issue on Windows.

Then, I started experimenting with various configuration variants, but nothing helped. The latest configuration is:

```
   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.aspectj.weaver" autoStart="false" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.caching" autoStart="false" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook" autoStart="false" startLevel="0" />
      <property name="org.eclipse.ui/org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
      <property name="org.eclipse.core.resources/encoding" value="UTF-8" />
   </configurations>
```

I am using latest ajdt version (which is compatible with Eclipse 2024-03):
https://download.eclipse.org/tools/aspectj/ajdt/431/dev/update/

The same issue occurs on version 2023-12 but not on 2023-09. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT.
After some more digging, I've come up with example (which unfortunately is not so small) which still causes the error to pop-up on Windows.

This is my *.product file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="Example App" uid="com.example.ide.product" id="com.example.ide.branding.product" application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" version="6.0.0" type="features" includeLaunchers="true" autoIncludeRequirements="true">

   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
      </programArgs>
      <vmArgs>-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Declipse.e4.inject.javax.warning=false
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-Xms256m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
-Djava.security.manager=allow
      </vmArgs>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
      </vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>

   <intro introId="org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal"/>

   <vm>
   </vm>

   <plugins>
   </plugins>

   <features>
      <feature id="com.example.ide.feature" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.jdt" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.platform" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.m2e.feature" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature" installMode="root"/>
   </features>

   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.aspectj.weaver" autoStart="false" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.caching" autoStart="false" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook" autoStart="false" startLevel="0" />
      <property name="org.eclipse.ui/org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
      <property name="org.eclipse.core.resources/encoding" value="UTF-8" />
   </configurations>

   <preferencesInfo>
      <targetfile overwrite="false"/>
   </preferencesInfo>

   <cssInfo>
   </cssInfo>

</product>
```

Below MANIFEST.MF of the plugin containing aspect:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Example Plugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.aspectplugin.core;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 6.0.0
Bundle-Vendor: example.com
Require-Bundle: org.aspectj.weaver,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-17
Export-Package: com.example.aspectplugin.core;aspects="TestAspect"
Eclipse-SupplementBundle: org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch
Automatic-Module-Name: com.example.aspectplugin.core
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-Activator: com.example.aspectplugin.core.Activator
```

And the aspect file, which does nothing but still causes the issue:

```
package com.example.aspectplugin.core;

import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.TypeBinding;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
privileged public aspect TestAspect {

    boolean around(TypeBinding that, TypeBinding s, TypeBinding t):
        execution(boolean org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.TypeBinding.sIsMoreSpecific(TypeBinding, TypeBinding, Scope))
        && args(s, t, ..)
        && this(that)
    {
        return proceed(that, s, t);
    }
}
```

Comment: @greg-449 Modifications to the JDT seems to be valid, because the code works on Linux and also when running the product from my dev IDE as 'Eclipse Application with Equinox Weaving'. For me it looks like product/osgi configuration issue.

Comment: Can you provide more details, please? What is "the product"? What exactly does it do and how is AspectJ involved? Can this problem somehow be made reproducible for the volunteers trying to help you? Apart from "the product", does AJDT as such work and build AspectJ projects normally?

Comment: By 'the product' I mean *.product file which is later used to build standalone application, it consists of some eclipse features plus set of custom plugins. AspectJ is used in one the custom plugins in various ways i.e. it adds some VM arguments to default JRE when the VM is started (i.e. end user runs some java code).

Comment: In case of Windows platform, it looks like weaving does not work at all in the launched application. On Linux it works correctly. Also the same code and configuration runs perfectly fine on both platforms when using Eclipse 2023-06.

I will try to prepare reproducible example.